# how to remove image from image field?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I created check box with ON and OFF option. When click on "ON" option then image show. I want to when click on "OFF" option then image remove or image filed empty

How to achieve this target in oracle forms 10g?

Comment: How did you *show* the image? Do the opposite to *hide* it.

Comment: with READ_IMAGE_FILE

now i want to hide when checkbox click on OFF option

Comment: Would SET_ITEM_PROPERTY with its DISPLAYED property set to FALSE do any good?

Comment: this image in block and block name DEPT and image filed name PIC

how to use in SET_ITEM_PROPERTY

Comment: It is described in Forms Help. Have a look. It varies from version to version (and you didn't specify which **Forms** version you use (database is 10g, as you tagged it).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this.

As someone suggested it, you could have thought using SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY (this one only applies to the current record). However, you cannot modify all the properties, only few of them : BORDER_BEVEL, INSERT_ALLOWED, NAVIGABLE, REQUIRED, UPDATE_ALLOWED and VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE.

Check the documentation of this method here (Oracle Forms v6i) : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a73074.pdf

One of the best solution you may find should be to make a custom Java Bean item which would handle this behavior. However be careful, Java Beans don't work correctly when used in a multi-records blocks. If your checkbox is used within a single-record block, it should be OK.

Here are some of my references to create your own Java Beans :

- http://devtalks.blogspot.com/2008/07/creating-and-using-java-beans-in-oracle.html
- http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/
- https://www.baigzeeshan.com/2010/02/how-to-add-java-bean-by-writing-your.html